# ANTLR String Template - How to specify a template with two multi-valued attributes?

Tags: antlr, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I have a scenario, where I need to instantiate an anonymous template using two multivalued attributes.

Here is what I tried from reading the documentation:

```
<mva_set1, mva_set2:{ x, y | Permit,IP,,<x>,,<y>,,,}; separator="\n">
```

For the sake of illustrating the problems, lets assume I am supplying the 
following two arrays to the two attributes:

```
string[] input_1 = new string[] { "128.230.0.0/16", "10.20.0.0/16" };
string[] input_2 = new string[] { "131.230.0.0/16", "154.20.0.0/16" };
```

I then applied the attribute using the following two function calls:

```
template.Add("mva_set1", input_1);
template.Add("mva_set2", input_2);
```

The result surprised me. I thought I will get four rows because I expected the template to be instantiated for each of the four pairs. However, what I got was just two rows from instantiating two pairs:

```
Permit IP 128.230.0.0/16 131.230.0.0/16
Permit IP 10.20.0.0/16 154.20.0.0/16
```

Am I using this incorrectly? Is there a better alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of output you get is the maximum size of any one list.
Ter